Ceramics SMD capacitor capacitance vs voltage rating, what is matters?
I’ve been working on laptop and I need to find replacement SMD caps
The original value is 0.015 uF/50 V.

This is the main power rail 19 V that also as a pw_protection circuit. The highside MOSFET was shorted before and I replace it.
Then I notice someone is here before me. And he replace this caps with unknown value/voltage rating. I just want to play safe and replace to proper state. I can’t find exact value on donor board.
Do I need really care about voltage rating or capacitance if I find replacement at least as close to the original value?

We don't know what the circuit is used for and what the capacitor does in the circuit. It may be important or not. Also please notice that the capacitor and many other parts in the circuit is marked "N/A" which may mean they might not be in the circuit to begin with.

@Justme this schematics uses green text if there’s “no stuff” related

From your screenshot the circuit seems to be power related, maybe part of a protection circuit. This will require more care in voltage rating because this means it will be a higher voltage than the logic circuits. The laptop power supply might hint at the nominal voltage this cap has to tolerate assuming you can trace this back to that supply.
As a power circuit, the common goals are either power storage or noise filtering. The size suggests filtering. There can be more room to select capacitance that are close but there are tradeoffs. A capacitance that is within 20-30% will likely function but it might not pass emissions testing if that is important to you. The more the value changes, the more it might affect actual device function.
The other parameters you don't have are the temperature tolerance and capacitance tolerance. Capacitor performance can changes with temperature, voltage, current, age, frequency, and size. So it is hard to know what is a proper replacement without knowing the original requirements.
That said, if you just need it to work for a while, a close value or even removing it could still make it work.

Yes it’s power procetion related. And it’s on main power rail. Thanks for advice appreciated

As a thumb rule, normally we use capacitors with 3x rating of operating voltage. For example, if a capacitor is used in 5V rail, then use 15V rated capacitors. It is really up to where it is used.
Does the voltage rating matter? Of course it matters.
If the capacitor you are use for replacement is rated for more than 50V, then you can use it blindly. If the rated voltage is less, check the operating voltage in your circuit, make sure the rated voltage is 3x the operating voltage. (There won't be a critical issue even if the rated voltage is more than operating voltage and less than 3x. Actual capacitance when you apply voltage will be less in this case.)

It’s 19v rail, thanks for advice. It did really help. Appreciated
